# How to assign the result of a query to a variable? (query optimization)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following columns: codigo_receita VARCHAR, valor_orcamento NUMERIC(30,2) and exercicio_orcamento INTEGER.

I created a query that works, but I would like to optimize it, without repeating code.

How do I assign the value of each query to a variable?

In order to get something like this:

```
SELECT
(query_1 - query_2) / query_2
AS changes
```

The query I created:

```
SELECT
((SELECT
    SUM(valor_orcamento)
FROM orcamento
WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2021
GROUP BY exercicio_orcamento)
-
(SELECT
    SUM(valor_orcamento)
FROM orcamento
WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2020
GROUP BY exercicio_orcamento))
/
(SELECT
    SUM(valor_orcamento)
FROM orcamento
WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2020
GROUP BY exercicio_orcamento) AS change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a single statement. You probably want to cast the result of the `sum()` to numeric otherwise the division would be an integer division:

```
SELECT (
         SUM(valor_orcamento) filter (WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2021) 
         - 
         SUM(valor_orcamento) filter (WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2020)
       )::numeric
       / 
       SUM(valor_orcamento) filter (WHERE exercicio_orcamento = 2020)
FROM orcamento
WHERE exercicio_orcamento IN (2020, 2021)
GROUP BY exercicio_orcamento
```

Comment: Better than I could even imagine, I didn't know the filter, but I didn't understand why it's necessary to use the sentence "WHERE exercicio_orcamento IN (2020, 2021)" after "from".
Considering that the records already been filtered after each SUM()

And just for curiosity, to learn more one thing.
Is it possible to do that like I was trying?
Assigning to a variable the output of a query?
If so, how could I do that?

Comment: @JoãoPedroReisSilva: it's mainly a performance optimization so it doesn't need to read all years just to calculate the result for two.